# Sed/Awk save text between patterns if contains string

Tags: command-line, email, sed, awk, find-in-files

I'm facing an issue with mails. I need to get all messages between 2 people:
`somebody1@domain.com` and `person@domain.com`.

The `file`:

```
From: somebody1@domain.com
to: person@domain.com
<body of the message1>

From: somebody2@domain.com
to: person@domain.com
<body of the message1>

From: somebody1@domain.com
to: person@domain.com
<body of the message1>

From: somebody3@domain.com
to: person@domain.com
<body of the message1>

From: somebody5@domain.com
to: person@domain.com
<body of the message1>
```

I tried to use the following `sed`:

```
sed -n "/From: [Ss]omebody1/,/From: /p" inputfile > test.txt
```

As a result I got all mails from somebody1 to `test.txt` file.

Question is: What should be the structre of `sed` to get only mails between somebody1 and person?

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^From: somebody1@domain.com/{h;n;/^to: person@domain.com/{H;g;p;:x;n;p;s/.//;tx}}' file
```

---

- `/^From: somebody1@domain.com/`: first search for the `From:` email-address

  - `h;` store that line int the hold space.
  - `n;` load the next line (the `to:` line).
- `/^to: person@domain.com/`: search for the `to:` email-address

  - `H;` append that line to the hold space.
  - `g;` copy the hold space to the pattern space.
  - `p;` print the pattern space.
  - `:x;` set a label called `x`.
  - `n;` load the next line (the email body)
  - `p;` print that line.
  - `s/.//` do a substitution in that line (just replace one character)...
  - `tx` ... that the `t` command can check if that substitution is successful (when the line is not empty, as in the end of the email body). If yes jump back to the label `x` and repeat until an empty line appears, if not jump to the end of the script.

The output:

```
From: somebody1@domain.com
to: person@domain.com
<body of the message1>

From: somebody1@domain.com
to: person@domain.com
<body of the message1>
```

Comment: Probably you can obtain an output more clean without the first `p;`. Just to avoid a list of isolated matches with `From: somebody1@domain.com` not followed by the second person match and the block of the letter.

Comment: @Hastur Good hint, I corrected it, now It's not printing isolated matches anymore

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I would like to ask another question:
thing is that what i should get in return is whole message body (which may containt new line characters) till next occurence of "From:" Right now i get more info but it's not enough:


example output
From: somebody1@domain.com
To: person@domain.com
Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2015 17:41:03 GMT
Subject: ***************
Content-type: *********************************
X-Scanned-By: **********************

and no body after it

Comment: Search for your file the point in which it stops your chunk, and _probably_ you will find another time the keyword `From: somebody1@domain.com`... You have to select a different unique key that you will not find again in the body of your message. It will be the same with the `awk` answer. Give it a try too.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk '/From: [Ss]omebody1/{flag=1;next} \
  /to\: person1/ {if (flag>0) {flag=2; print; next} else {flag=0; next}} \
 /From/{flag=0} {if (flag==2){print NR,flag, $0}} ' input.txt
```

- `/From: [Ss]omebody1/{flag=1;next} \` Put a flag variable to 1 on match and skip the line.
- `/to\: person1/`  If the flag is 1 update it to 2 else reset it to 0.
- `/From/{flag=0}`  On match it reset the flag value.
- `{if (flag==2){print NR, $0}}` if flag is 2 it will print the *linenumber* and the line.

Change the value of `person1` to have different matches.

Input file used

```
From: somebody1@domain.com
to: person2@domain.com
<body of the message1>

From: somebody2@domain.com
to: person1@domain.com
<body of the message2>

From: somebody1@domain.com
to: person1@domain.com
<body of the message3>

From: somebody1@domain.com
to: person1@domain.com
<body of the message4>

From: somebody3@domain.com
to: person@domain.com
<body of the message5>
```